# Order preserving injective map from a wellordering into itself

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Assume $\langle A,\prec\rangle$ is a wellordering. Prove that if $f: \langle A,\prec\rangle\rightarrow\langle A,\prec\rangle$ is a (1-1) order preserving map, (not necessarily an order isomorphism), then for all $x \in A$, $x \le f(x)$.

It seems that by contradiction I could just say the following:

suppose $f(x)$ is strictly less than $x$,
then since $A$ is a wellordering it has a least element, $x'$
so $f(x')$ would be less than $x'$ meaning $f(x')$ is not in $A$
This contradicts the fact that the map is into $A$.
Therefore $x$ is less than $f(x)$ for all $x$ in $A$.

I feel like Im missing something though. This doesn't seem thorough enough.

Comment: It looks like you're misreading $f(x)\prec x$ for some $x$ as implying $f(x)\prec x$ for every $x$. Just because this happens at a fixed $x$ doesn't imply it happens at the least element $x'$; think of the function on $\mathbb{N}$ that sends every number to zero. Of course, this isn't injective, and the point is that it's impossible to give an injective example.

Comment: Contradiction of the statement is $\exists x\in A$ such that $x<f(x)$, and there's no guarantee that this $x$ is the least element of $A$.

Comment: Please: Look at my edits.  Your way of writing MathJax code makes no sense.  Don't write $x$ and then $\le$ and then $f$ and then $(x)$.  Just write $x\le f(x)$, with a single pair of dollar signs.  You get proper spacing that way.  Also, I changed $<A,\prec>$ to $\langle A,\prec\rangle$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You're argument can't be right because you didn't use the assumption that $A$ is well-ordered, only the weaker fact that $A$ has a least element, which is not enough. For example the closed unit interval $[0,1]$ has a least element, but the map $f(x)=x^2$ is an order-preserving injection which does not satisfy $x\le f(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: I actually gave this exercise for my students last week. This follows from the fact that if $f\colon A\to B$ is an order embedding of well-ordered sets, and its image is an initial segment of $B$, then every $g\colon A\to B$ which is an order embedding satisfies $f(a)\preceq_B g(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hole in your argument is that you’ve concluded that $f(x')\prec x'$ without actually giving any justification for the conclusion. Try this approach instead: let $B=\{x\in A:f(x)\prec x\}$, and suppose that $B\ne\varnothing$. Then $B$ has a $\prec$-least element; call it $b$. Use $b$ to get a contradiction with the hypothesis that $f$ is $1$-$1$ and order-preserving.

Comment: Thanks for that. f(b) is not a member of B leading to the contradiction that b is less than or equal to f(b) which is strictly less than b

Comment: @user108896: Yep, that’s got it. You’re welcome.